# Cypress : how to forward response body JSON to be used on headers

Tags: node.js, cypress

i'm gonna test REST API using Cypress.io , but using chaining request, it wants to be work like this, JSON response body on the first API will be used on the next API Headers for Authorization

I'm already try doing by using cypress commands and printing on console.log, but seems like it does not captured on the log, or is there any clue for this, or i just using another command like cy.route ?

```
Cypress.Commands.add("session", () => {
    return cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/auth/',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: {
        "client_secret" : ""+config.clientSecret_staging,
        "username": ""+config.email_staging,
        "password": ""+config.password_staging
      }
    }).then(response => {
      const target = (response.body)
    })
  })

  it('GET /capture', () => {
    cy.session().then(abc =>{
    cy.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/capture/'+target 
    })
      })
    })
```

the goal is to capture parse of JSON array from `target = (response.body)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- leave the code as is, be aware that the

```
.then(response => {
  const target = (response.body)
})
```

code isn't returning anything so the `cy.session().then(abc =>{ ...` code is getting the whole `response` (`abc` is the response of the first `.then`)

- change the code into

```
.then(response => {
  const target = (response.body)
  return target // I added this return
})
```

and then your `abc` param will be equal to `response.body` and not to `response`

That's because if you don't return a subject from your chainable calls the default one will be passed to the next `.then` function.

Let me know if it satisfies your issue.

p.s. Welcome

Comment: thanks for helping me out, using `return` actually solved the problem and the way you told me here was the simple one, thankyou! Actually previously, i solved this issue by using another method, using write files and insert to fixtures files, then reuse the output of the fixtures for chaining to other request.

Comment: Nice one! Did you solved it another way because mine was wrong or because you are more comfortable with that? If it was the former case I'll update my answer 

Comment: sorry updated, i think your solution is the simple one, thanks